# Magento 2 module still working after dependent module is getting disabled

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, dependency

I'm trying to make a depend module A to module B using  tag in module's config file. But if I disabling module B, module A is still working. How one can fully define dependency in Magento 2?

In general:
what is the difference between "**Soft Dependency**" and "**Hard Dependency**" in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

In `module.xml` you can define only sequence of module loading, not dependencies of modules.

Dependencies of modules are defined in `composer.json`. Hard in section `require`, soft in section `suggest`

See Magento 2 [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/modules/mod_depend.html) for more info.

Comment: I thought composer is not being checked when magento is running codes. Does magento checks composer.json each time a page request being processed ?

Comment: No, it's checks only on cli commands that can install/uninstall disable/enable module, like `bin/magento module:disable`. Checks at runtime will be to expensive

Comment: How can I depend my module in another in inside my module folder ? Is there anyway or I should edit global composer.json ?

Comment: module still working even after I added the require depndency in composer.json :/

Comment: As KAndy said, M2 does not check dependencies at runtime. If you disable a dependency, you _might_ get errors, but you won't get any 'missing dependency' fatal error like you would in M1.

Comment: @RyanH. So, the superising thing for me is that, if I'm disabling module B which module A is depend on it, module A is still working great. So, where is the dependency here ? Module A is still working!

Comment: @MichelGokan How do you do disabled the module? Because you cannot disable module without disable module dependent on it with module:disable command.

Comment: @KAndy `php bin/magento module:disable`

Comment: php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Catalog

Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_Catalog because modules depend on it: ...